# Validation error messages are shown repeatedly in struts2

Tags: struts2

I m new to struts2. I am doing client side validation for my form. The error messages for validations that i wrote in properties file are repeated each time i submit.

e.g.

**First submit**

```
username required
```

**Second submit**

```
username required
username required
```

Please tell me how to clear previous error messages?

Comment: Can you please post some code related to that so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should give example from your code. There is a [document](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax-validation.html) about Struts2 client side validation and about Ajax Validation there writes:

```
clearValidationErrors(formNode) : Removes validation errors from a form
```

so you can try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a table on ur jsp to display the form, then make sure that the table is a parent of the form tag. If the table is a child of form tag, the validation messages wont get cleared each time. Making the form tag as a child of table tag would solve your problem.

Comment: This is true. I found that using cssClass="myTableStyle" was the easiest workaround in most cases. (I had to dig into the template files to find this. For some reason, style="myTableStyle" did not work though I think it should.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the spring integration you have to define your bean as `scope="prototype"`, then you get a new instance of your Action for every request.

It's a good idea to do this for every Action.